# Preview option for visual studio for xamarin for ios project

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am using visual studio(VS) in my windows system as well as visual studio for Mac in my macbook air.In macbook system I am able to preview my xaml design in VS but in windows system ,there is no option to preview my xaml code.Everytime I need to connect to macincloud using macAgent to test the simple design change.So I was wondering if there is any option through which I can preview the code in windows without launching it in stimulator?I tried gorilla player but it seems it works for stimulator only.

Comment: Did you try, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer?tabs=vswin ?

Comment: Build your project on target platform and open View->Other Windows->Xamarin.Forms Previewer.